# Не обновляется panelgroup в jsf

Tags: java, jsf

Пытаюсь обновить по кнопке компонент `panelgroup`, но ничего не происходит. Я уже пробовал многие способы и ничего не помогает. Подскажите, что ещё можно сделать, чтоб обновить `panelgroup`?

```
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="content">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="nav">
                <h:form id="itemsMenu">
                    <h:commandLink value="View" update="workplace" actionListener="#{main.determineAction}">
                        <f:param name="link" value="Viewing telephone book"/>
                    </h:commandLink>
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup id="workplace">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{main.responseRendered}">
                    <ui:include src="#{main.linkPage}"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

Код бина

```
@ManagedBean(name = "main")
@ViewScoped
public class MainBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<String>      listItemsMenu;
    private String            linkPage;
    private boolean           responseRendered = false;

    public boolean isResponseRendered() {
       return responseRendered;
    }

    public void setResponseRendered(final boolean responseRendered) {
       this.responseRendered = responseRendered;
    }

    public String getLinkPage() {
       return linkPage;
    }

    public void setLinkPage(final String linkPage) {
       this.linkPage = linkPage;
    }

    public void determineAction(final ActionEvent event) {
       final Locale currentLocale = SessionBean.getCurrentLocale();
       final MessageManager messageManager = new MessageManager(currentLocale);
       final Map<String, String> mapParameters = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
       final String linkType = mapParameters.get(Constants.ATTRIBUTE_LINK_TYPE);
       if (linkType.equals(messageManager.getProperty(
                           Constants.MESSAGE_MENU_VIEWING))) {
           linkPage = Constants.PAGE_VIEW;
       } 
       ...
       responseRendered = true;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<h:commandLink render="workplace" ... >
```

Вообще html компоненты входящие в реализацию `jsf` (`Mojarra`, `MyFaces`) используют термины `jsf ajax` стандарта: `render` - обновить компоненты с указанными `id`, `execute` - отправить значение компонентов на сервер. Термины же `updete` & `process` используют переопределённые `ajax` реализации, например `PrimeFaces`.